# MVC C# API - Return RootObject with list attribute instead of just returning a list

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I'm adding an API controller to my MVC application to retun JSON data

In my application I have a class called Album:

```
public class Album
{
public int Id { get; set; }
public string AlbumName { get; set; }
public int YearReleased { get; set; }
public string AlbumInfo { get; set; }
public string imgAlbumCover { get; set; }
}
```

My database contains a table of several Album objects

I created an API controller to return this list of Albums in Json format.

I added the following code to WebApiConfig.cs to get JSON back instead of XML:

```
using System.Net.Http.Headers;




GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters
.JsonFormatter.MediaTypeMappings.Add 
(new System.Net.Http.Formatting.RequestHeaderMapping("Accept",
                          "text/html",
                          StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase,
                          true,
                          "application/json"));
```

When I do an Albums API call in the browser, returned is a list of Album objects in JSON format.

Instead of returning the list of Albums, I'd like to retun a RootObject that has 1 property called Albums, where Albums is a list of Album objects. Is there a way of doing this in the controller? I don't want to have to create a new RootObject class.

Below is the code for my API controller:

```
 namespace Music.Controllers.API
 {
    public class AlbumsController : ApiController
     {
      private MusicContext db;

      public AlbumsController()
      {
        db = new MusicContext();
      }


      public IEnumerable<Album> GetAlbums()
      {
        return (db.Albums.ToList());
      }

    }
  }
```

Comment: So do it then... create another class that has a property of `List<Album>` and return that instead. I don't understand what you are having a problem with

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure why this is causing you trouble. You can return any class you like.

Comment: This is what I planned on doing. So you have to create a root album class for every table? I was wondering if there was a way to do this in the controller, without having to create all those new classes.

Comment: Change the `GetAlbums` return type to `HttpResponseMessage` and change the return statement as `return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new {Albums = db.Albums.ToList() });`. This is the way you don't need to create a new class.

Comment: user1672994, This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: I will post that as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Then create a viewmodel as such and return the same like

```
public class AlbumListResponseModel
{
 public IEnumerable<Album> Albums { get; set; }
}

 public async Task<IActionResult> GetAlbums()
  {
    AlbumListResponseModel model = new AlbumListResponseModel
     {
         Albums = db.Albums;
     } 
    return OK(model);
  }
```

If you are using `WEB API 2.0` then consider using `IActionResult` rather

Answer (score 0):

Change the `GetAlbums` return type to `HttpResponseMessage` and change the return statement as

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new {Albums = db.Albums.ToList() });
```

That's way you don't need to create a new class.

Full Code :

```
namespace Music.Controllers.API
 {
    public class AlbumsController : ApiController
     {
      private MusicContext db;

      public AlbumsController()
      {
        db = new MusicContext();
      }

      public HttpResponseMessage GetAlbums()
      {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new {Albums = db.Albums.ToList() });
      }

    }
  }
```